# Multiple json objects using a single xhrget call(dojo)

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is it possible to load multiple json files through a single xhrget call??? can anybody provide me some references or code snippets please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Return a complex data structure: `{call1: {}, call2: {}, call3: {}}` or `[{}, {}, {}]`

Comment: do you have multiple json "files" you want to load or do you want to send multiple JSON objects in an AJAX response? depending on the need different solutions can be worked out

Answer (score 0):

You can hold multiple json objects within another json object. So make your xhrget call to a "method" that gathers all the json objects you need warps 'em in a containing json object and then returns that containing json object

You can then get each of the json objects that you actually want to use out of that returned containing object

Comment: Thank you philf2b...can you please provide me a sample code snippet?

Comment: I think this does not deserve a code snippet. We don't even know which server-side architecture you have... Make the server-side method that philf2b read all your json files on your server, then return the output as a higher level json structure, as John Strickler mentionned above.